# how to make multiple http calls synchronously at different levels in angular 2 using rxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I want to make multiple http calls synchronously at different levels in angular 2 using rxJS
For Eg , I am having a resolver service which handles 5 api calls like a,b,c,d and e.

I want them to execute in this order and I am not using any of those output values as input so I need all responses only at end.

first a should be called and once api is completed 
second b,c, d
third after b,c,d completed then e should be called

In activated Route , I need to retrieve those values and use it 
I have already tried below stuff but I am getting response of A and E only and I could not able to fetch the values from inner observable

```
resolve(a,b){
 return A.flatMap(data=> {
      return forkJoin (
                 B,C,D)
                  }).flatMap(xres => {
                                 return E
                                 })
}
route.data.dataA
route.data.dataBCD
route.data.dataE
```

Comment: I am using Angular 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one resolver that takes care of all 5 requests, in order to ensure their order of execution, then it would make sense to return the results of those 5 requests as one element. Try with the following:

```
import {Observable, forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
import {mergeMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

interface AFoo { }
interface BFoo { }
interface CFoo { }
interface DFoo { }
interface EFoo { }

class FooService {
  doA(): Observable<AFoo> { throw new Error("Not implemented"); }
  doB(): Observable<BFoo> { throw new Error("Not implemented"); }
  doC(): Observable<CFoo> { throw new Error("Not implemented"); }
  doD(): Observable<DFoo> { throw new Error("Not implemented"); }
  doE(): Observable<EFoo> { throw new Error("Not implemented"); }
}

interface CompositeFoo {
  aFoo: AFoo;
  bFoo: BFoo;
  cFoo: CFoo;
  dFoo: DFoo;
  eFoo: EFoo;
}

export class FooResolver implements Resolve<CompositeFoo>{
  constructor(private fooService: FooService) { }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<CompositeFoo> {
    const forked$ = forkJoin(this.fooService.doB(), this.fooService.doC(), this.fooService.doD())
                    .pipe(map(([bFoo, cFoo, dFoo]) => ({ bFoo, cFoo, dFoo })));
    return this.fooService.doA()
      .pipe(
      mergeMap(aFoo => forked$.pipe(map(forked => ({ ...forked, aFoo })))),
      mergeMap(result => this.fooService.doE().pipe(map(eFoo => ({ eFoo, ...result })))),
      map(result => ({ ...result }))
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this answer works with Angular 5+, but not Angular 2. The `pipe` method was introduced in Angular 5 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the angular version, is plainly related to rxjs. OP originally used the tag rxjs6 (rxjs v6.x), so he most likely uses angular v5.x or v6.x

Comment: Developers srsly need to stop using "angular 2,5,6" to describe the framework. It makes no sense.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo We really can't avoid the major version when asking or answering questions as some APIs might be obsolete or not recommended to use in one version where as in another version there might be a better/improved way of doing this. So it make sens to know which version of Angular they are using in their project.

Comment: Agree, but notice that there is a difference when talking about angular2 and angular v2.x. For some ppl, talking about angular2 is equivalent to both angular v2.x , v5.x, etc. Basically, for some angular2 is the framework itself, independent of the version, which is sadly the result of a wrong decision of the angular team back in the start. @Ritesh

Comment: Yes, it should be like Java.. but the difference is that.. these versions are released so fast and the transition from AngularJS to Angular have changed the mind of the people. They are scared whenever a new version is released. There are some people who thinks Angular 6 altogether is a new framework especially the business people :)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Ok, didn't see the rxjs6 tag when it was posted. I saw OP's code, where flatMap is used as an observable method, which isn't supported in rxjs6, so I assumed (s)he actually uses Angular v2.x and not v6.x

Comment: @Jota.Toledo It is very useful and saved my time . Thanks for your prompt response. It was working as expected now. If we put const Fork$ before A, its get called so I move it inside and worked as expected. really thankful to you for your great help. Also the code looks good now because I am getting those values using properties instead of using index when we retrieve from fork join

Comment: @ArunsaiBK I rejected your edit, as removing the constant `fork$` reduces readability and it shouldnt really have the sideeffect that you describe. If you can provide a small reproduction of the situation that you describe, Ill be happy to edit the answer myself

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have tried and got exception that A response was not there because it start executes fork$(B,C,D) before executing A service. after changing , it is working fine.